# how can I upload and parse an Excel file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I want to be able to upload an Excel file that contains contact information.  I then went to be able to parse it and create records for my Contact model.

My application is a Rails application.

I am using the paperclip gem on heroku, I've been able to parse vim cards into the Contact model, and am looking for something similar, but will go through all lines of the Excel file.

Gems that simplify the task and sample code to parse would be helpful!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Spreadsheet is the best Excel parser that I have found so far. It offers quite a lot of functionality.

You say you use Paperclip for attachments which is good. However, if you store the attachments in S3 (which I assume since you use Heroku) the syntax for passing the file to spreadsheet is a little different but not difficult.

Here is an example of the pure syntax that can be used and not placed in any classes or modules since I don't know how you intend to start the parsing of contacts.

```
# load the gem
require 'spreadsheet'

# In this example the model MyFile has_attached_file :attachment
@workbook = Spreadsheet.open(MyFile.first.attachment.to_file)

# Get the first worksheet in the Excel file
@worksheet = @workbook.worksheet(0)

# It can be a little tricky looping through the rows since the variable
# @worksheet.rows often seem to be empty, but this will work:
0.upto @worksheet.last_row_index do |index|
  # .row(index) will return the row which is a subclass of Array
  row = @worksheet.row(index)

  @contact = Contact.new
  #row[0] is the first cell in the current row, row[1] is the second cell, etc...
  @contact.first_name = row[0]
  @contact.last_name = row[1]

  @contact.save
end
```

Comment: hi, this seems simpler to use...can you explain the logic of the last do-block...having a little difficulty fully understanding it...

Comment: also...what is stored in @worksheet.row(index)...is it the array by columns?

Comment: Sure, @worksheet.row(index) will return the row at index, so if index is 0 then it will return the first row, if 1 then the second, etc. The last block will start from index = 0 and loop until index is last_row_index, in other words the index for the last used row in the excel worksheet. In my example I don't actually do anything with the row, I only show how you can access it.

Comment: @DanneManne --- I see I see, thanks....I guess I am still slightly confused in terms of how to parse the specific columns in a row, when one row is the same as a record?  For example, for a Contact model, I have first_name, last_name as methods, and also as columns....thanks...going through the docs but not quite connecting....

Comment: Okey, added an example of what it might look like to read data in cells and put each row into a model instance.

Comment: cool, this is helpful, both of your answers are -- I am thinking of making the parsing a method in the model that stores the uploaded file....good idea?

Comment: @DanneManne -- hi, sorry for the question, will the to_file work on s3 (using heroku)...why to_file verus just path method?

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar requirement in one of my Rails 2.1.0 application. I solved it in the following manner:

In the 'lib' folder I wrote a module like this:

```
require 'spreadsheet'

module DataReader
  def read_bata(path_to_file)
    begin
      sheet = book.worksheet 0
      sheet.each 2 do |row|
        unless row[0].blank?
          # Create model and save it to DB
          ...
        end
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e
    end
  end
end
```

Had a model Upload:

```
class Upload < AR::Base
  has_attached_file :doc, 
    :url => "datafiles/:id",
    :path => ":rails_root/uploads/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  # validations, if any
end
```

Generated an UploadsController which would handle the file upload and save it to appropriate location. I used Paperclip for file upload.

```
class UploadsController < AC
  include DataReader

  def new 
    @upload = Upload.new
  end

  def create
    @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])

    @upload.save
    file_path = "uploads/#{@upload.id}/original/#{@upload.doc_file_name}"
    @upload.read = DataReader.read_data(file_path)

    # respond_to block
  end
end
```

Read about 'spreadsheet' library [here](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/) and [here](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/files/GUIDE_txt.html). You can make appropriate improvements and make the technique work in Rails 3. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, looks like yours got some good upvotes...still reading through it...you built the Upload with paperclip?  And it reads the data upon upload?

Comment: Do you need to create a separate view and a form to upload the file?

Comment: Yes. I use paperclip to upload and have different views for creating the upload and I process the file and read data upon upload.

Comment: I see thanks -- almost ready to run it live to see if it goes...made some mods but this is helpufl, thank you @sam!

Answer (score 0):

I made a gem to achieve this easily. I called it [Parxer](https://github.com/platanus/parxer#usage) and...

- It's built on to of [roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) gem.
- It allows you to parse xls, xlsx and csv files.
- Has a DSL to handle:

  - Column mapping.
  - File, row, and column/cell validation.
  - Column/cell formatting.