# Excel file upload and choosing columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, file-upload

I'm building a website which allows users to upload an Excel file. The Excel file may have many columns of irrelevant information, so I want to display an interface which allows the user to select the columns he wants.
Is there already a gem to do this is Ruby on Rails? If not, any suggestions on what APIs etc. to use and how to go about implementing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer on SO which I think covers most of what you're looking for: [how can I upload and parse an Excel file in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825473/how-can-i-upload-and-parse-an-excel-file-in-rails)